# .NET framwork 4.6 32bit or 64 bit

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am wondering if .NET framework has a version for 32 bit or 64 bit? It looks like .NET core has 32 bit version and 64 bit version download separately, but when I search .NET framework 4.6 download, there is one download available. It installed to c:\program file(x86) directory, .NET framework 3.5 was installed to both c:\program file and c:\proram file(x86)

Comment: Because the installer automatically detects the bitness of your operating system, and install accordingly (x86 on x86 machines, while x86+x64 on x64 machines).